# Errors on building the MySql JDBC driver from source

Tags: mysql, jdbc, javac

When I try to build the JDBC driver, from the source downloaded from [here](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) , I get many compilation errors. For example,

`The type CallableStatement must implement the inherited abstract method CallableStatement.getCharacterStream(int)`

in CallableStatement.java line 57

All these error indicate, I thought, that the driver is compatible with JDK 1.5, because the specified method wasn't part of the JDBC spec in JDK 1.5.

However, when I tried to build the driver with JDK 1.5, I got errors indicating that JDK 1.6 is required. For example,

`The import java.sql.RowIdLifetime cannot be resolved`

where `RowIdLifetime` is a class that wasn't part of JDK 1.5.

So, which one is it? JDK 1.5 or 1.6? Am I missing something when I try to build?

Comment: Uh - why do you want to *BUILD* the JDBC driver?  You should just be able to take the .jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar is in the same .zip or .tgz archive) and start *USING* it.  No assembly required :)

Answer (score 1):

Having read the file `connector-j.html` that is bundled with the source, it looks like I need both:

> If you are building Connector/J 5.1 make sure that you have both JDK 1.6.x installed and an older JDK such as JDK 1.5.x. This is because Connector/J supports both JDBC 3.0 (which was prior to JDK 1.6.x) and JDBC 4.0. Set your JAVA_HOME environment variable to the path of the older JDK installation.

Next time, I'll RTM before posting.

Comment: I'm still curious why you need to "build" anything at all.  The pre-built .jar file should run anywhere, on any platform.  Is it just out of curiousity on your part, or is there a genuine requirements that's forcing you to build it?

Comment: I'm playing around with it for purposes not related to this question. If you're still interested, I'll discuss further.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just worried that maybe you thought you NEEDED to build your own .jar.  Glad you were able to answer your own question - and good luck with your project!